# Create video using text and music using FFmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am beginner in android. I want to merger text and music and make video using FFmpeg. I searched a lot but was unable to find any sample application. Any helping link or tutorial will be appreciated thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Pete: Actually i am searching for helping link. if you think this is off-topic i can remove this ?

Answer (score 0):

you'll probably want to use a pre compiled version of ffmpeg for android. [Here](http://www.roman10.net/2011/07/17/how-to-build-android-applications-based-on-ffmpeg-by-an-example/) is a tutorial you could try